# How can I install react in this situation

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I am trying to develop react with MacBook now.

The following error occurs when you use the create-react-app. command.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJiEX.png)

Please help me solve this problem.

Maybe the development environment is completed using react??

Answer (score 1):

Run this command, hopefully, It will resolve your issue.

`sudo npm install -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

I think Nodejs is not installed correctly.Nodejs must be installed to download and run React dependencies.

You can download:
https://nodejs.org/en

Then, restart your computer

and then, you can use react dependencies:

```
npx create-react-app your-application-name
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

If you still get the error try this:

```
npm create vite@latest
```

Comment: Node is installed, otherwise it would say `zsh: command not found: npm`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid using `create-react-app` (according to [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487) PR). [Here](https://hackernoon.com/create-react-app-is-dead-here-are-some-alternatives) you can find some good alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions in the folder. you can do a

```
ls -al
```

if your user doesn't have the permission, you can try a

```
chown -R $USER:$USER .
```